# How should I capitalize "Clean Up the Tags and Branches" as a title to a section?

Tags: capitalization, titles, headline-case

Specifically, I am wondering how "Clean Up" should be capitalized.  I have three plausible options:

1. "Clean Up"
2. "Clean-up"
3. "Clean up"

It all really depends on what part of speech "up" is and whether it requires hyphenation.

I was thinking that "clean up" is a phrasal verb and... I don't know...

Comment: You need to give some context, John. Do you mean the words to be a Noun Phrase or a Verb Phrase? If a Verb Phrase, is the mood, as seems likely, imperative? Are they part of a title, or do they occur in a piece of continuous text?

Comment: It is imperative, as a title to a section in a technical paper.

Comment: Then for me it would be 'Clean up the tags and branches'. Phrasal verbs, in no matter what form, do not need a hyphen. Some people like to capitalize the intitial letters of all words in a title. That's fine, too.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Working with Subversion, eh? :-)

As you said, *clean up* is a phrasal verb. *Cleanup* is a noun. (Hyphenation isn't appropriate for the verb form. If it were, I wouldn't capitalize "up.")

I agree with Barrie England's comment. You should capitalize "up" in the title because the linkage between the two words in a phrasal verb isn't as strong as if they were hyphenated.

Comment: Migrating from SVN to Git, actually. :)